# compile-time conversion char* to bytes

Tags: c++

I have a lot of conversion from const string (known in compile time) to byte string.
Now I do it using this function:

```
std::string StrToHex(std::string);
"0f120a" -> {0x0f, 0x12, 0x0a};
```

But it take a lot of time, I'd like to generate all this string in compile-time.

Comment: `constexpr` comes to mind.. also, why are you taking your input string by value rather than `const&`?

Comment: You could do this with `char*`, but `std::string` itself is not supported (till c++20 at least) at compile time.

Comment: What is the "byte string" while returning `std::string`? Is it `"0f120a" -> "\x0f\x12\x0a"`?

Comment: How can I do this with char*? I would'nt write everywhere {0x0f, 0x12, 0x0a} instead "0f120a"

Comment: Thanks a lot constexpr is what I need. I forget add reference in declaration of function there

Comment: Consider:  Let string[i] be (for example), 0x30.  This can be output as "30" (and prefixed with 0x if you need it).  It is also (and can be output as) the letter '0'.  It is also (and can be output as) 48 decimal.  No conversion is needed.   Does it simplify your efforts to understand / believe that string S1's 'data' IS A byte array?

Comment: Hmmm.  Maybe my understanding of 'conversion' is different than yours.  Can you elaborate on your belief?  What is a "conversion from const string to byte string".   You probably need to show more code ... see also [MRE]

Answer (score 0):

> conversion from const string (known in compile time) to byte string

To demonstrate that the data (of a string) is **already** a byte string,
Consider the following code

---

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::hex, std::dec;

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <iomanip>
using std::setw;


// s1 does NOT change
const string s1 = "0123456789Ab";

cout << "\n  letters: ";
for (uint i=0; i<s1.size(); ++i)
{
   cout << "  " << setw(4) << s1[i];
}

cout << "\n      hex: " << hex;   // format info
for (uint i=0; i<s1.size(); ++i)
{
   cout << "  " << setw(4) << static_cast<int>(s1[i]);
}  //                      // ^^^^^^^^^^^ use the char as an int 

cout << "\n  decimal: " << dec;
for (uint i=0; i<s1.size(); ++i)
{
   cout << "  " << setw(4) << static_cast<int>(s1[i]);
}  //                      // ^^^^^^^^^^^ use the char as an int

cout << "\n  letters: (confirm s1 did not change)";
for (uint i=0; i<s1.size(); ++i)
{
   cout << "  " << setw(4) << s1[i];
}
```

---

Output ... the bytes of string can be printed as chars, hex ints, or decimal ints.

```
  letters:      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     A     b
      hex:     30    31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38    39    41    62
  decimal:     48    49    50    51    52    53    54    55    56    57    65    98
  letters:      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     A     b
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to address what they are actually trying to do

Comment: I agree ... because I think no 'conversion' is needed.  The demo is intended to show that there is no run-time (effort or impact) to use the string elements as what ever is needed by the app.  The elements are already bytes.

Comment: There are legitimate reasons for wanting a representation of `{0x0f, 0x12, 0x0a}` , e.g. you need to write those 3 bytes to a stream